# PHP write soap request to file

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

what I'm trying to do it setting up an XAMPP apache, creating a script on it, which is once it is called, writing down into a file:

- HTTP header attributes
- content (body - like webservice XML etc.)

This seems to be a small thing, however it looks like I'm not able to find a solution via google...
Help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$request = "";
//printing headers
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
   $request.= "$name: $value\n";
}
//printing body.. this part does not work any of it...
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
   $request.= "$name: $value\n";
}
//$request.="++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
foreach ($_FILES as $name => $value) {
    $request.= "$name: $value\n";
    //$request.="++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
    foreach ($value as $name2 => $value2) {
        $request.= "$name2: $value2\n";
        //$request.="++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
    }
}
$request.=$_FILES['document.xml']['D:\Software\xampp\tmp\phpA521.tmp'];
$request.=@file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('result/'.date('Y-m-d H_i_s').'.log',$request);
?>
```

Comment: What are we supposed to help you with ? Writing the code for you ?

Comment: Sorry you are right, i forgot to post

Comment: And what is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: No error, just no content... neither POSTS, documents, nor attachments

Comment: Did you issue a post request? If so, can you show the HTML code of the form you submit?

Comment: So basically i m not sending a form, the posts parameters are echoed only  by coincidence, the body (content) of the message is soap (xml) in this case:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>"
<soapenv:Header>
//header attributes...
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<escb:echoMessage xmlns:escb="http://escb.ecb.int/echo-ET>"
<escb:freeText>adfasdf</escb:freeText>
<escb:freeInteger>1</escb:freeInteger>
</escb:echoMessage> 
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` variable only gets populated for specific request types. [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) describe `$_POST` as:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* or *multipart/form-data* as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

In your case the Content-Type is different and should/will be specified as:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
```

There is a similar restriction on the `$_FILES` variable. [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) state:

> > **Note:**
> > Be sure your file upload form has attribute *enctype="multipart/form-data"* otherwise the file upload will not work.
>
> The global `$_FILES` will contain all the uploaded file information.

To get access to the posted data, do as explained in the [documentation on I/O streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use `php://input`

So you would do this as follows:

```
$postedData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You could then parse this as XML:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string(trim($postedData));
```